# Lightning Web Component (lwc): Passing multiple parameters to a class

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters from lwc to an apex class? I tried searching for a way to do, but have not found an answer yet.

I would like to pass the recorded as well as a value from a dropdown list. I am able to pass the if using the following code, but don't know how to pass the value from dropdown list too:

```
@wire(getContacts, {accId:'$recordId' }) //this is where I would like to add another parameter
  contacts;
```

Here is the code:
javascript:

import { LightningElement,api,wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactData.getContacts';

export default class RecordIdExample extends LightningElement {
     @api recordId;
     @track value = "Seattle";

```
 get options() {
     return [
        { label: 'Seattle', value: 'Seattle'},
        { label: 'New York', value: 'New York' },
        { label: 'Chicago', value: 'Chicago' },
    ];
 }

 handleChange(event) {
     this.value = event.detail.value;
 }
@wire(getContacts, {accId:'$recordId' })
  contacts;
```

}

html:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
            <lightning-combobox
        name="bed"
        label="Search Criteria"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Select Search Criteria"
        options={options}
        onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>

        <p>Selected value is: {value}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="boarder">
        <template if:true={contacts.data}>
            <ui>
                <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                    <li key={contact.Id}>{contact.Name}</li>
                </template>
            </ui>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

The idea is to get contacts from location selected by the user.

Comment: It's as simple as putting the parameter inside the parameter object (`{accId:'$recordId',otherParam:'$otherParam'}`). Where are you getting stuck? How can we help you?

Comment: I am getting stuck on including the value from the dropdown that the user has selected.

Comment: Please include all relevant code by making an [edit]. The more information we have, the better we can assist you.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. Added the code to my original question.

Comment: @sfdcfox: your suggestion worked. I had the code as :

({accId:'$recordId'} ,{otherParam:'$otherParam'})

and that is why it was not working for me earlier.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll add an answer for others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of the parameters need to be specified in the second parameter of wire:

```
@wire(getContacts, {accId:'$recordId', value: '$value' }) contacts;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Looks like it applies to imperative Apex calls too.  I was getting the error "invalid apex method invocation. apex methods only accept a single argument", and combining the parameters into a single object worked.

Comment: @Memetic Yes, and also similarly to Aura server calls.